# library for clientside vcard creation

Tags: jquery, verification, vcf-vcard, client-side, hcard

I would like my site visitors to be able to create a vCard, with all supported properties, notes, and some custom properties. Similar to what this [website called vacrdmaker](http://vcardmaker.com/) offers. I have found a php library for [codeigniter](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/vCard_Library/), and and old standalone called stab.nu/vcard/ and a pear package called File_IMC. But would like to use a jquery library or plugin to do it completely clientside, and to offer life verifiction (format phonenumber, email, url,...) Have not found anything here or on github. Is there anything like this out there yet? Maybe its better to look for hcard creation in jquery and convert it to vCard?